# App Engine datastore to Android listview

Tags: java, android, eclipse, google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints

I have set up a basic entity class in my App Engine backend.

```
`@Entity`
`public class Club {`

  `@Id`
  `private int id;`
  `private String clubName;`

  `public Club() {`
  `}`

  `public int getId() {`
  `return id;`
  `}`

  `public void setId(int id){
      this.id =id;
   }`


  `public String getClubName() {
    return clubName;
  }`

  `public void setClubName(String clubName) {
  this.clubName = clubName;
  }
}`
```

I have generated the cloud endpoint class and generated the cloud endpoint library.
I want to be able to populate the clubName from the datastore into a listview in android but not sure how to do this. 
I'm trying to follow this https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/endpoints/consume_android but so far I am unable to understand what to do. I'm new to this and would be greatful if anyone lead me in the right direction please.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the below steps to achieve your objective:

1, As mentioned in the google doc on consuming cloud endpoints in android, ready your app by adding the required libraries and make API calls and then on getting data from your backend, you can store that data into a SQL database. You can do this step in the onpostexecute method of your asynch task

```
protected void onPostExecute(ScoreCollection scores) {
// Do something with the result. maybe the store the data to sqlite database
}
}
```

To know how to store data in SQLITe database please refer  http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html
http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidSQLite/article.html

2, Now query data from your SQLITE db into a [cursor](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteCursor.html) and then use a [simplecursoradapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SimpleCursorAdapter.html) to display the data from cursor on a [listview](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html) in your layout or activity screen

An approximate piece of code will have steps like below:

```
yourcursor = yourdatabase.query; //this is the cursor returned from querying your db
adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this.getActivity(), R.layout.onerowinalistview,  yourcursor, FROM, TO,0); // this connects the columns of your DB mentioned in FROM array to the elements in a row of your list as mentioned in TO array
ListView yourlistview = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.yourlistview);//this is the listview element in your screen layout
yourlistview.setAdapter(adapter); // setting the adapter to the listview
```

Hope this helps